# powershell azure Vnet list from Region selected

Tags: powershell

I am developing a powershell script ,I have list all regions from the v-net in a subscriptions but How to list all v-net from selected region?

I'm creating a Powershell script for Azure virtual network list based on regions selected from the subscricptions

Comment: Can you share what you currently have?

Comment: Do you mean, the filter should only be region based on all subscriptions or filter should be applied on both subscription and region as well?